# Как выводить фото автора в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Как выводить с помощью get_avatar() аватарку автора как backround-image, чтобы получилось что-то вроде:

```js
 <div  style="background-image:url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url('full'); ?>)">
```

Comment: Есть функция get_avatar_url()

Answer (score 1):

Никак. [get_avatar()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_avatar) выводит аватарку только в виде тега img. Но, есть альтернатива в виде [get_avatar_url()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/get_avatar_url).

```
<div  style="background-image:url(<?php echo get_avatar_url( $GLOBALS['current_user'], array(
    'size' => 48,
    'default'=>'wavatar',
) ); ?>)">
```

Примерно как-то так...

Comment: у меня водится только     'default'=>'wavatar', нo  картинка которую я поставил как аватарку для автора не вводится.

Comment: Скорее всего WP по каким-то причинам не видит Вашу картинку. Вообще WP обычно берёт аватары с gravatar. Если у пользователя аватара там нет, то выводится аватар по умолчанию. "Свои" аватары можно добавлять при помощи специальных плагинов (например, WP User Avatar). Из коробки такой функционал не доступен.